# Polygon cartographic line templates dysfunctional

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I have been exasperated by the simple task of symbolizing polygon boundaries with custom dashed lines.  I have a polygon representing property boundaries and I want dashed lines that are uniform-spaced with short line segments (to accommodate smaller line segments in actual polygon which is composed of variable-length line segments).  However, using the 'Cartographic Line Template' option to create these in the feature's symbology labyrinth of popup boxes is producing randomly askew line segments, where they should simply go from point A to Point B.

Note: I have tried this without the black border - JUST the red dashed lines - simple and bare bones parameters to boot.  Also using a template with interval = 1.  Same deal.

[image: Symbology]

**SYMBOLOGY**

[image: Template]

**TEMPLATE**

[image]

**OUTPUT**

Comment: On your outline properties, is there an offset?

Comment: There is indeed.  However I tried with the same cartographic template (and many simple variations thereof) with NO offset.  And just one good old-fashioned border - i.e. just the red dashed line in my screenshot.  Same problem.  Offset is not the culptit.